# continuity with 2-variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

The question is

Determine whether $f$ can be defined at $(0,0)$ so that is is continuous $$f(x,y) = \frac{x^py^q + x^ry^s}{x^qy^p + x^sy^r}, p,q,r,s > 0$$.

I chose numbers for p,q,r,s and calculated the limit for different (x,y) and I found that
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} f(x,y) = \frac{a}{b}$$.

But what does this mean? Did I even answer the question?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want $f$ to be continuous at $(0,0)$, you need to check that $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)^{+}} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)^{-}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f$ is defined everywhere except at the axis (i.e. except at points of the form $(x,0)$ or $(0,x)$), lets call this set $A$. The questions asks whether you can define $f(0,0)=\text{something}$ so that $f$ becomes continuous at $(0,0)$. Note also that $f$ is continuous in $A$.

I'll put an example with a different function, define $f,g:R-{0}\to R$ as $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $g(x)=1$ if $x>0$. Note that you can extend $f$ by defining $f(x)=0$ and still get a continuous function but you can't do that for $g$: no matter how you define $g$ in $0$ it will always be discontinuous at $0$.